# Initializing fields within a class C++

Tags: c++

I saw the following code in a book and am wondering what is going on:

```
class shiftedList{

      int* array;
      int offset, size;

public:       

         shiftedList(int sz) : offset(0), size(sz){
               array = new int[size];
        }        

}
```

what is going on with offset(0) and size(sz) in the constructor of the class?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Look up `initializer lists`.

Comment: The fields after the colon will be initialized with those values, in this case offset will be 0 and size will be initialized to sz. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list)

Answer (score 1):

They are just initializers as part of the constructor.

So in this specific case it is equivalent to

```
shiftedList(int sz) {
   offset = 0;
   size = sz;
   array = new int[size];
}
```

Except that the compiler can do better optimization, and the initialization may not actually result in any code.

There are case where initializer list **has** to be used, specifically those where a reference variable is being initialized.

Comment: They are not equivalent to that. For example, consider a reference member.

Comment: That is true -- im not able to think of a better word than "equivalent" to describe the similarity

Comment: I have to agree with @chris, there are situations, where you have to use the member initializer list.

Comment: @Soren _'im not able to think of a better word than "equivalent" ...'_ Narrow it to be applicable for this particular use case.